# Java euler program error

Tags: java

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

project euler found solution I get an `array out of bounds error`

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.*;

 //print the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000
 public class multiples_of_3_and_5 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int mult3[] = new int[200];
    int mult5[] = new int[200];


    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i+=3 -1) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= mult3.length; x++) {
            mult3[x] = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i+=5 -1 ) {
        for(int x = 0; x <= mult5.length; x++) {
            mult5[x] = i;
        }
    }

    int threeTotal = IntStream.of(mult3).sum();
    int fiveTotal = IntStream.of(mult5).sum();

    System.out.println(threeTotal);
    System.out.println(fiveTotal);


}

}
```

Comment: Well, the exception is due to `x <= mult3.length`, which should be `x < mult3.length`, but I believe your implementation is wrong regardless of that typo.

Comment: don't be so static. Use more dynamic stuff - put the numbers in `ArrayList`. In that way you don't have to know the number of numbers that you need to store.

Comment: And also - you can count the sum in the first loop. Then you don't need that `int threeTotal = IntStream.of(mult3).sum();` line

Comment: Access to `mult3[mult3.length]` is out of bounds. Array goes from 0 to length-1.

Comment: What do you think `i+=3 -1` is doing? Is this really what you want? Also, the problem is asking for one sum, not two separate sums.

Comment: Divide 999 by 3 and see if the array `int mult3[] = new int[200];` actually has correct bounds or not.

Comment: 1. Use ArrayList instead of regular array. 2. Use modulus (%) to find multiples of 3 and 5. 3. You can find all the multiples within a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without any loop. Just calculate the sums of the relevant [arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

The sum of an arithmetic progression is n(a<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>n</sub>)/2, where a<sub>1</sub> is the first element, a<sub>n</sub> is the last element and n is the number of elements.

The sum of the multiples of `3` between 1 and 999 is `(3+999)*333/2`

The sum of the multiples of `5` between 1 and 999 is is `(5+995)*199/2`

Both of these two sums include multiples of `15`, so you have to subtract the sum of the multiples of `15` between 1 and 999, which is `(15+990)*66/2`

Therefore the total required sum is

```
(3+999)*333/2 + (5+995)*199/2 - (15+990)*66/2
```

Comment: True to solve the arithmetic problem. Probably not true to help new coder to learn how to use loops and count :)